# Is it possible to send page content via email using UI5?

Tags: sapui5

My application is designed to create a table which is later edited by the user. After this I need my application to send the page content via email.

I used URLHelper's trigger email() but through this I am able to trigger the email with to, cc, subject, text body but my ui5 application is not able to insert the table into the email.

Can someone please suggest something? or is it even possible?
I won't mind using plain javascript either, Point is I need to do this without using the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do something similar on one of our apps. I added a button to the screen which when clicked invokes a 'mailto', and populates the email client with the to, subject and body. The body is created as part of the script. We basically read the table contents into an array, then loop through the entries using a forEach. Keep in mind using mailto or even the URLHelper does not allow you to use HTML formatted text in the 'body' of the email. So, if you're looking for something pretty, you may be out of luck.

```
    onNotifyUserPress: function(oEvent) {
        var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
        var oBinding = oItem.getBindingContext();
        // Set some vars for the email package
        var sEmpEmail = oBinding.getProperty("Smtp");
        var sEmpName = oBinding.getProperty("STEXT_2");
        var sEmailSubject = "Your Subject " + sEmpName;
        // Create DateFormat Object
        var oDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy"});

        // Retrieve Table Data
        var oTable = this.getView().byId("yourTable");
        var aTableData = oTable.getBinding("items").getContexts();
        // Build the email body
        var sBody = sEmpName + " - Some Body Text\n\n";
        sBody += "Field 1 | " + "Field 2 | " + "Field 3 | " + "Field 4" + "\n";
        // Loop through table data and build the output for the rest of the email body
        aTableData.forEach(function(oModel) {
            var oModelData = oModel.getObject();
            var sEndDate = oDateFormat.format(oModelData.Vendd);
            var sStatus = this._formatStatus(oModelData.ZQ_STAT);
            sBody += (oModelData.Essential === "X" ? "Yes" : "No") + " | " + oModelData.Ttext + " | " +  sEndDate + " | " + sStatus + "\n";
        }.bind(this));
        // Open email client window and prepopulate with info
        window.open("mailto:" + sEmpEmail + "&subject=" + sEmailSubject + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(sBody), "_self");
    },
```

You'll obviously need to update the code to point to your table data. In this particular instance, we have an object page with a couple of sections. Each section contains a table which loads a list of entities that are associated with the user. As the data is already loaded and exists in the model, this may not work in the same fashion as what you're trying to do (if I understand correctly), as you need to send an email after the data is entered/modified?

Hopefully this can at least get you started!

Cheers!